# Перевод "Return to the Stack Overflow homepage."

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

После того, как очередь опустела, выводится следующее сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю изменить перевод "Вернуться на Stack Owerflow на русском главную". Первое, что приходит в голову:

> Вернуться на главную страницу StackOwerflow на русском

Но меня смущает количество `на` в одном предложении. Еще один вариант:

> Вернуться на главную страницу сайта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может, так: «Вернуться к вопросам? Главная страница [StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).»

А то получается повторение слова «вернуться».

Comment: Да, как-то я забыл про предыдущее предложение. Отличный вариант.

Comment: Исправил согласно предложенному вами варианту.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, похоже, изменения уже вылиты на сайт. Добавите `status-resolved`?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Добавил статус.

Answer (score -4):

Мне кажется это мелочь, и не стоит заострять на этом внимание